# How to Import module with spaces using @testable

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, ui-testing

Sounds like a silly question, but was wondering how should I import modules with spaces ?

I am following [this](http://natashatherobot.com/swift-2-xcode-7-unit-testing-access/) link to add test cases, but my project has a space, say `foo bar`. So how should I import using `@testable`

`@testable import foo bar` throws error

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I also had this issue and finally figured out that a underscore `_` are the replacement for spaces in module names.

So you should write the following.

```
@testable import foo_bar
```

Comment: You saved my time.Thank you very much